# How to generate asm code from so module ARM android?

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, arm, disassembly

Before i used objdump but it's not what i need. What toolchain in android ndk will output asm code?

I need this code for compilation via gcc compiler and compile this back to so module.

Please don't close this topic, i tired create new ones because previous is closed, i explained properly.

Comment: If you edit your questions to fix the major problems, they can be *re-opened* (and downvotes removed if the original voters see the improvement).  Now this question is lacking too many details and doesn't show your attempt using objdump to disassemble / modify / reassemble.  Or edit this one to include the attempts from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692779/compile-arm-asm-to-so-module-file-problem / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60717203/how-to-generate-asm-code-from-so-module-arm-android **including the actual asm you tried to assemble**.

Comment: In other words, you want to disassemble an ELF file such that the assembly code can be modified and then re-assembled?

Comment: I edited https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692779/compile-arm-asm-to-so-module-file-problem and added all info.

Comment: @Erlkoenig
I want to make some changes in asm code and compile again to so module.

Comment: This is very complicated, since (relative) addresses need to be converted into labels and such. Perhaps radare or IDApro can do this. It's not possible with objdump.

Comment: Your edit on [Compile ARM asm to .so module file problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60692779) still didn't show the exact commands you used, *or* the asm source that the error message is complaining about.  It's not ready for re-opening in that state.  Questions about error messages you don't understand must have an [mcve] of what produced the error.

Comment: @PeterCordes That wouldn't help anyways, it was created by `objdump` which can't produce re-assemblable-code at all. If stuff only needs to be modified, and nothing inserted, it might be easiest to hand-modify the file via hex editor...

Comment: @Erlkoenig: yeah true, complying with SO rules in this case might be a pointless exercise.  But if you're going to leave in the error messages then you need to at least show one of the (non) asm source lines you fed to the assembler to get that error message.  The current state of the question is the worst of both worlds: an error message from a false start on doing this.  (Good point that just stripping the left columns can't work because you need branch target labels.)  There are some Q&As about disassembling/reassembling x86 executables instead of ARM.  (mostly the answer is "it's hard")

Comment: @PeterCordes Here is some asm code created by objdump:
https://pastebin.com/4dGfSEp0

Comment: @user2105483: yes, I know what objdump output looks like.  The point is to copy/paste a couple lines that you tried to assemble *into the SO question that has the error message*, as a [mcve].  Remember you're trying to communicate your question clearly to any/all people that might read your question.  I'm trying to get you to improve your question so it's in a fit state to exist on this site.  Leaving important info buried in comments is not helpful.

Comment: Since these functions are PIC-wrappers for library functions, they will be called from many places throughout the file. If you added/removed a single instruction, the size of the functions would differ, and all the (relative) addresses in the file were wrong. So, being able to re-assemble that file (by removing the first two columns and the function names) would be pretty useless.

Comment: @PeterCordes this file contains 465K lines, i don't think this info should help, i asked about principle how to make this.
So right now edit hex is the only solution. Because add/remove some instructions affect on offsets.

Comment: @user2105483: are you even reading what I wrote about how to edit your previous question?  I said to include *a couple* lines as an *example*.  Or to remove those error messages entirely if you don't want to show where the error came from.  (Or delete that old question again since you *did* post this one instead of fixing your old one.  Apparently you still haven't understood how to write a clear question that doesn't need more explanation in comments.)